# Pandas plot doesn't show colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

That's a part of my data:

```
    index   errno
63  1709    1
33  1536    1
123 3052    1
148 3403    1
164 4303    1
```

I try to plot in in a bar plot. I created list with colors for every bar:

```
['green', 'green', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'pink']
```

My current chart looks that:
[image]

So my problem is that every bar have the same color.

Code to print this plot looks that:

```
my_color = df['index'].apply(
    lambda x: 1 if x < 1500 else 
                  (2 if x < 2000 else (3 if x < 3000 else (4 if x < 3500 else (5 if x < 4000 else 6))))).map(
    {1:'red',2:'green',3:'black',4:'yellow',5:'white',6:'pink'}).tolist()
df.plot(
    kind='bar', x='index', y='errno', figsize=(15,7), rot=60, color=my_color)
plt.show()
```

my_colors looks that:

```
['green', 'green', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'pink', 'yellow', 'pink', 'green', 'green', 'pink', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green', 'yellow', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green', 'yellow', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'pink', 'pink', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'green', 'yellow', 'green', 'green', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'pink', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'yellow']
```

Pandas version 20.3

How can I change the bar color according to the my list?

Comment: This was a bug. Update your pandas installation.

Comment: That's right after update it's work good. Thanks